# send request to the server each [X] hours: flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app running on multiple devices and I need each device to send a request to the server each `X` hours to update its status (battery level, its location.. etc)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to work with the work manager , which is used to do tasks in a specific time even if the app is closed , i work with it but with android ,but in flutter there's a package from flutter that handle this with android and ios
this is the link to the package [work manager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager).